# Is it possible to record video and overlay with CALayer simultaneously using AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, video-capture

I'm currently working on app that records video of user, binds particle emitters to hands landmarks on preview. In result effects are shown on camera preview, but they aren't captured on video.

I saw a great tutorial on AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool https://www.raywenderlich.com/6236502-avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos, but that way it only is possible to rendere animations on already recoded video.

I wonder if there is any chance to use AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool for recording video form camera and animations in real time. Or if you know other method to do it, without diving deep in metal and so on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello Pavlo, 
Did you found any solution to achieve this? I'm looking for a possible solution exactly for this issue.
Cheers!

Comment: Hello, Tamas! Unfortunately, I haven't found any solution with AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool or anything else native. Cheers!